# Adding ng-controller stops AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

With the below HTML AngularJS is invoked and the webpage prints "5" as the result of {{10/2}} in the "body".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <title>AngularJS</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>hello angular</h2>
    {{ 10/2 }}
</body>
</html>
```

When I add an ng-controller:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <title>AngularJS</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainController">
    <h2>hello angular</h2>
    {{ 10/2 }}
</body>
</html>
```

with the script.js:

```
var MainController = function($scope){

    $scope.message = "Hello!"
}
```

AngularJS stops working and the webpage prints {{10/2}} instead of 5. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `script.js`, change

```
var MainController = function($scope){

    $scope.message = "Hello!"
}
```

**to**

```
app.controller('MainController', function($scope) {

  $scope.message = "Hello!"

});
```

> [**Working Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/zbGwOkhPB8m60ChTtOQj?p=preview)